# Teams Custom Connector, get the installed channel, teams details

Tags: microsoft-teams, connector

When developing a Teams Custom connector, I need to get the details where the connector is installed like teams id,channel id, teams Name, channel Name   etc and pass those to the backend along with the webhookUrl and userId .
How should I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

For this, you can use the microsoft/teams-js library provided.
Import the app package from it.
and use the following code snippet.

```
   const teamInfo={
        channelId:'',
        channelName:'',
        teamId:'',
        teamName:''
    };
    
    app.getContext().then((context) => {
        console.log("checking");
        console.log(context.channel.id);
        console.log(context.channel.displayName);
        teamInfo.channelId=context.channel.id;
        teamInfo.channelName=context.channel.displayName;
        teamInfo.teamId=context.team.groupId;
        teamInfo.teamName=context.team.displayName;
    });
```

then you can post teamInfo along with the config.webhookUrl, and other details